# remove port number from the url

Tags: url, tomcat, port

I have two instances of tomcat on a single machine both instances accepting secure request. Suppose:
one has connector port configured as 8080 and redirect port as 443. The other one has connector port configured as 8083 and redirect port 444. So if first tomcat receive request as

http://localhost:8080/abc/index.html

it then redirect to https://localhost/abc/index.html

and if 2nd tomcat receive request as

http://localhost:8083/abc/index.html

it then redirects to https://localhost:444/abc/index.html

now my problem is that i want to remove that port number 444 from the url. Is there any way to remove that or hide that. I can't use same port number 443 for both the instance.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that. The web browser will only connect on port 443 for HTTPS if you don't specify a port.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an additional static IP address to your computer and assign the second Tomcat to use 443 on *that* address. Add to your `hosts` file to use a non-numeric name.

```
192.168.1.99  localhost2
```

Comment: can you please explain how to do this?

Comment: Googling for `windows add static ip address` and `windows add host entry` should get you through it fairly easily.